# While not EOF in another while not EOF not working in ASP CLASSIC

Tags: html, asp-classic

The below code breaks when I place a while not EOF in another while not EOF. 
Is this illegal in ASP Classic code? How do I fix it?

```
<table cellspacing = "0" cellpadding = "3" class = "horiz ">
    <tr>
        <th width = "20%">Acronym</th>
        <th width = "50%">Meaning</th>
        <th width = "30%">Source</th>
    </tr>
    <%
    count = 0
    pletter = "z"
    fletter = left(con("acronym"),1)
    %>
     <% while (NOT con.EOF) %>
    <tr>
        <td colspan = "3" ><h2><a name="A">A</a></h2></td>
    </tr>
     <% while (NOT con.EOF) %>
    <tr>
        <td><%=con("acronym")%></td>
        <td><%=con("meaning")%></td>
        <td><%=con("source")%></td>
    </tr>
     <%
    con.MoveNext()
    Wend
    %>
    <%
    con.MoveNext()
    Wend
    %>
</table>
```

Comment: I want to execute the first while loop once, then the next while loop and repeat the process until EOF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not have a single while loop. Add an if statement to determine if the first character has changed (E.g., from A to B). If the character changes, add a TR to display the character.

```
dim lastCharacter = ""
while (not con.EOF)
    dim firstLetterOfAcronym  = left(con("acronym"),1)
    if lastCharacter <> firstLetterOfAcronym then
       rem show TR of firstLetterOfAcronym
       lastCharacter = firstLetterOfAcronym 
    end if

    <tr>..... show row as usual </tr>
    con.MoveNext()
wend
```

Comment: i will leave you to work out the missing parts from my pseudo code above.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your recordset sorted on the Acronym .

This is exactly like @Valamas his solution, meaning a single loop, but a bit more complete example.

```
<table cellspacing = "0" cellpadding = "3" class = "horiz">
    <tr>
        <th width = "20%">Acronym</th>
        <th width = "50%">Meaning</th>
        <th width = "30%">Source</th>
    </tr>
    <%
    mainletter = ""

    While (NOT con.EOF)
        letter = Left(con("acronym")
        If mainletter <> letter Then
            %>
            <tr>
                <td colspan = "3" ><h2><a name="<%=letter%>"><%=letter%></a></h2></td>
            </tr>   
            <%
            mainletter = Left(con("acronym"),1)
        End If
        <tr>
            <td><%=con("acronym")%></td>
            <td><%=con("meaning")%></td>
            <td><%=con("source")%></td>
        </tr>
        <%
        con.MoveNext()
    Wend
    %>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Once you get to the end of the recordset (via the loop) it does not reset back to the start (unless you tell it too) so once you get to the end of the recordset in the first loop when the second loops start it is already at the end.

I would rewrite your code as it is not really logical but if you want your code to work as is add a movefirst after the loop ends to go back to the start of the recordset.

```
...
</tr>
 <%
con.MoveNext()
Wend
con.movefirst
con.MoveNext()
Wend
%>
</table>
```

Edit: Actually you'll end up in a loop if you do this, clone the recordset before the first loop and loop two different recordsets with the same data. Otherwise re-write to be a little cleaner.

Comment: I don't like this solution very much at all. Makes no sense to loop through each record twice.

Comment: I don't like it either, you should re-write your code to not have to loop twice but that is what the original poster's code was and therefore I modified it to work answering his question. You can't vote me down for using his code and answering his question :)

Comment: But, you are supposed to (try) to give helpful answers, not letting someone do the wrong thing.